# i just got suffrage badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

but i havn't used 30 votes today? is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

Some badges are checked infrequently, the criteria for some badges change occasionally and sometimes new badges are added..  Have you ever used up all 30 votes in a day?  I am pretty sure the suffrage was recently added or tweaked, since I was also recently awarded it, and I am quite sure that I have used all 30 of my votes many times over the last ~500 days.

See this post.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68024/i-was-just-awarded-the-suffrage-badge-without-proper-cause

Comment: correct -- you will get the badge if *on any day* you used all 30 votes.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it's a good or a bad sign that only 147 people have earned that badge on ServerFault?

Answer (score 0):

When badges are added, they can be retroactive, meaning that you will receive the badge if you have met the conditions in the past. This happened to me recently, where I was awarded Suffrage on a number of the sites where I was visiting them for the first time in a day.